iOS App shows languages with regions that are not selected in Xcode
My iOS app shows more language with region codes than what I've selected in Xcode:

This is what I see in the language selection (simulator and device):

How can I remove all the language with region codes? I want to remove:

English (US)
Suomi (Suomi)
Deutsch (Deutschland)
Kalaallisut (Kalaallit Nunaat)
Norsk bokmål (Norge)


Are these languages that you added before but then thought you had removed? The post Xcode 11 - Removing localization might help.

What is your base locale?  English(US)?

@Paulw11 The base is just "English", I've turned on "Use Base Internationalization"

@BenzyNeez Thank you. Our CI builds the app from a clean state, so there's no left-over cache or something. Also .lproj-wise I only have de.lproj, en.lproj etc. one for each language as defined in Xcode.
